# Paste into mail and keep format of pasted text but don't change to that format thereafter

Tags: email, copy-paste, formatting

This annoyance occurs every time I paste something into an email I am editing in OS X Mail. Here is what happens every time:

1. I am composing my email in the default format.
2. I paste something in, which is in a different format, that I want to preserve. This occurs automatically, and is not a problem at this point.
3. The annoyance occurs when I resume typing after the pasting, and the format has now changed to that of the pasted text and I need to reset it.

I am hoping there is some simple solution to this annoyance which occurs for me many dozens of times per day.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

- Write the first paragraph.
- Write part of the the second paragraph.
- Go back to the end of the first paragraph and press <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> a couple of times.
- Paste whatever will change the text style into the space you've just created.

Not very elegant but it does the job.

Comment: Thats what I do for a workaround. But not elegant as you say. Thanks.